# Javascript's window.open function after an ajax request avoiding any popup blockers

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, paypal, window.open

To sum it up, I collect address info, and the method of payment the user chooses, then via Ajax validate the info with PHP and if the validation fails either show the errors or will redirect the user in a new widow to PayPal. I know that window.open must be within an on click so that is the issue. I tried having the whole Ajax stuff in a function and calling the function then the redirect all within a large on click but it hasn't worked.Any ideas?

<- UPDATE ->

Not great but it was solved by adding a new step, opening a nifty modal with a prompt and success message.

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible with an asynchronous request. // Perhaps you could do validation on a per form field basis, using change/blur handlers – and then your actual submit button only gets _enabled_ once all validation requirements are satisfied, and then `window.open` called on the button click _directly_ won’t get blocked. (Also see how much of the work HTML5 Form Validation features might already be able to handle for you, without any additional AJAX requests.)

Comment: Thanks man, async: false actually makes it work on firefox. As for your, not much has change but thats for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you will probably need two steps in your ui, the first click validates the data via ajax, and then a button appears on success that says something like "success! open paypal". It's a kludgy UX but it will be solid in terms of implementation.

Comment: In other words, and correct me if im wrong, add an additional step for the user to take?Might as well thanks.